# Why is angular2-webpack-starter not working with angular-material?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-material

I want to modify angular2-webpack-starter(https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) to work with angular-material (https://material.angular.io/)

I followed instructions on angular-material website and imported everything, though when I run the application I hit an error here:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

It appears to not be able to find the import above even though I installed the package successfully.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/platform-browser/animations' in 'myprojectdirectory'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 40:0-79
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and reinstall the packages again

Comment: you are running angular2 or angular4?

Comment: am running angular 2.4

Comment: Version of @angular/animation?

Comment: @Vignesh "latest", so.. 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Updating the packages to latest version change the configuration in Webpack. See the below code

```
  plugins: [
           new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
             /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        )
]
```

Comment: Silly question, but whenever I install new packages I can just do the typical import without having to modify webpack configuration, whats so special about this animations that makes me have to do what your posting?

Comment: You can check in old version packages that you can find index.d.ts file. Without Index file the importing will not work . so after updating  latest version of packages the index.d.ts file is removed then it throws error